# SELECT query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, wxpython

I am trying to retrieve values from a PostgreSQL database in a variable using a WHERE clause, but I am getting an error.

The query is:

```
select age into x from employee where name=name.GetValue()
```

`name` is the textcontrol in which I am entering a value from wxpython GUI.

I am getting an error as name schema doesn't exist.

What is the correct method for retrieving values?

Answer (score 5):

"name.GetValue()" is a literal string, you are sending that to your db which knows nothing about wxpython and nothing about the variables in your program. You need to send the value of that data to your db, probably using bound parameters. Something like:

```
cur.execute("select age from employee where name=%s", [name.GetValue()])
x = cur.fetchone()[0] # returns a row containing [age] from the db
```

is probably what you're after. This will create a query with a placeholder in the database, then bind the value of name.GetValue() to that placeholder and execute the query. The next line fetches the first row of the result of the query and assigns x to the first item in that row.

Comment: am still getting an error as - (psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying =?)
is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Yeah, psycopg uses %s style parameter binding, not ?, I've edited my answer to reflect this. Be careful, the execute line there is not the same as `cur.execute("select age from employee where name=%s" % name.GetValue())`, using string interpolation (the % operator) would open you up to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive what you are trying to do, but I think your issue might be syntax (misuse of INTO instead of AS):

```
SELECT age AS x FROM employee WHERE name = ....
```